# SSRS filtering a series (not a group) or using multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services, charts, filtering, series

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but searching hasn't given me a solution and I hope someone can help.

I am working on a simple chart.   X axis is the date (day), Y axis is a simple number (1 to 100).

I have totals, for 3 different sites, per day.  I need a line for each site on the chart.

```
   Day   |  Site  | Value
---------+--------+-------
 Monday  | site X |  30 
 Monday  | site Y |  45 
 Monday  | site Z |  20 
 Tuesday | site X |  35 
 Tuesday | site Y |  26 
 Tuesday | site Z |  12
```

and so on..

There is only 1 total value per day, per site.

I am trying to create 3 lines on the chart, one for each site but I can't figure out how to filter on the series level.  (I'm working on a very large date range, so lines work better visually rather than doing a series group of bar charts, or even stacked bar charts)

I originally tried the multiple dataset work around (using an expression and something like

```
sum(field!total.value, "site X")
```

but that didn't work (it showed only a straight line, the first value I think) .  Now, I have one dataset, but I can't find a way to filter series so they only show for one site.

I also tried this IIF

```
=iif(Fields!site.Value = "site X", fields!total.value,0)
```

but that gives a weird looking line.

I can't believe this is not possible in a chart in SSRS, I mean, it's pretty basic, so I must be missing something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a chart as follows

[image]

- The Values are the actual numbers you are attempting to chart
- The Category groups as set up here are the individual dates.
- The Series Groups are your Sites

At this point I then set the Horizontal Axis to be in Scalar/Dates format so the designer looks as follows

[image]

When you run this report using an adaptation of the (brief) dataset example above you get the following

[image]